# LinkButton Send Value to Code Behind OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have a ASP `LinkButton` Control and I was wondering how to send a value to the code behind when it is clicked? Is that possible with this event?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ENameLinkBtn" runat="server" 
    style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 8pt;"
    onclick="ENameLinkBtn_Click" ><%# Eval("EName") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Just add to the `CommandArgument` parameter and read it out on the `Click` handler:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ENameLinkBtn" runat="server" 
    style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 8pt;" CommandArgument="YourValueHere" 
    OnClick="ENameLinkBtn_Click" >
```

Then in your click event:

```
protected void ENameLinkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string yourValue = btn.CommandArgument;
    // do what you need here
}
```

Also you can set the `CommandArgument` argument when binding if you are using the `LinkButton` in any bindable controls by doing:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SomeFieldYouNeedArguementFrom") %>'
```

Comment: You can declare the sender as LinkButton and skip the typecasting:

    protected void ENameLinkBtn_Click(LinkButton sender, EventArgs e)          {
    string yourValue = sender.CommandArgument;
    // do what you need here
    }
(Sorry, I tried but I CANNOT format the code)

Answer (score 4):

Add a CommandName attribute, and optionally a CommandArgument attribute, to your LinkButton control.  Then set the OnCommand attribute to the name of your Command event handler.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ENameLinkBtn" runat="server" CommandName="MyValueGoesHere" CommandArgument="OtherValueHere" 
          style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 8pt;" OnCommand="ENameLinkBtn_Command" ><%# Eval("EName") %></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"/>
```

Then it will be available when in your handler:

```
protected void ENameLinkBtn_Command (object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "You chose: " + e.CommandName + " Item " + e.CommandArgument;
}
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try and retrieve the text property of the link button in the code behind:

```
protected void ENameLinkBtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string val = ((LinkButton)sender).Text
}
```