# How to call a function on Ok click of a confirmation pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I click on Image button , I get a confirmation pop up to select either Yes or No.

After clicking Yes, I want to call a function : `objOwn.CloneIssue(Eval("id_tbl_issue"))`

Can you please suggest how to do it .

My code so far:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Imagebutton ToolTip="Clone this Issue." Text='Click' ID="hpr_link_edit" 
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/clone.png" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" 
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Clone?');" /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Imagebutton ToolTip="Clone this Issue." Text='Click' ID="hpr_link_edit" 
                ImageUrl="~/Images/clone.png" 
                CssClass="textbox" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Clone?');" /> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there - the key thing is this line, which you've already figured out:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Clone?');"
```

If the confirm returns **true** then the method in the `OnCommand` property will execute.  If the confirm returns **false** then nothing will happen.

All you need to do is add an `OnCommand` property, specifying the associated handler method in the code behind (which should then call your clone code).

If you want to pass the `id_tbl_issue` value through to the handler, you could put it into a `CommandArgument` property, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5381699/483162).  Obviously you will need to swap LinkButton for your ImageButton:

```
OnCommand="YourMethodName" CommandName="Clone" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id_tbl_issue") %>'
```

To understand how to create the handler, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.oncommand(v=vs.110).aspx.  Unfortunately I'm a C# developer so I'm not really familiar with the VB.NET syntax.

Comment: I want to perform below function if the answer of confirm is yes : Function CloneIssue(ByVal el As Integer) As String

            Return "../edit/clonen.aspx?issue=" & el

        End Function

Comment: What should I give in Onclick= ? , when i give CloneIssue , it throws an error, please suggest

Comment: Sorry, have updated - you'll need to use OnCommand instead.  The MSDN link I provided shows you how to wire up the method with the OnCommand property.  Then, in that method you can call your cloning code.

Comment: <ItemTemplate> <asp:Linkbutton  Text='Click' ID="hpr_link_edit" 
          CssClass="textbox" runat="server" 
         OnClientClick="return confirm('Clone?');" 
         OnCommand="Objown.CloneIssue" CommandName="Clone" 
         CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id_tbl_issue") %>'/> </ItemTemplate> 
         </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Do you have a comment/question?  If so please ask it rather than just pasting code!

Comment: The question was related to the above question , that's why to avoid duplicate one  i commented rather than posting a new question

Comment: But you didn't ask a question, you just pasted some code!  I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

My code is this:-

```
Response.Write("<script>var confirmdelete=confirm('No chronological event found.Do you want to continue ?');if (confirmdelete) {('<%=ASPxButton_Approve%>').valueof()}</script>");
```

After I click approve button it will show yes no confirmation box. It is showing but my problem is I want to call method "approve()" after user click YES from confirmation box.